# Django URL regex "is not a valid regular expression" error

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm having a bit of trouble configuring the following url. I want it to be able to match a pages which start off with a category and then finish with a slug, examples:

```
/category1/post1/
/category2/post2/
/category3/post3/
/category1/post4/
/category2/post5/
```

I've tried many different methods with no success... I always get an "is not a valid regular expression" error.
This is how I thought it should work:

```
url(r'^(?P<category1|category2|category3>[\w\-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', blog_post, name = 'blog_post'),
```

I am fairly new to regex and trying to learn so any help on this one with an explanation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Change `category1|category2|category3` to `category` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is incorrect; you are putting the alternative values in the wrong place. You put them in the *name* of the group:

```
(?P<category1|category2|category3>...)
```

Put them in the part the name is supposed to match instead:

```
(?P<category>category1|category2|category3)
```

Making the full registration:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>category1|category2|category3)/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', blog_post, name='blog_post'),
```

I'm assuming your `blog_post` callable looks something like:

```
def blog_post(category, slug):
```